# What is `assignment`formatting for `PHP alignment` in Netbeans PHP option?

Tags: php, netbeans, code-formatting

As I guess, this is about the code formation for multi-line assignment such as this [post](http://diigo.com/0ktwh) has fully described.

> ...example 
>   **$server = 'localhost';
>
>   $port = 80;** 
> the equal signs would be
>   made to "line up", the second statement getting more whitespace
>   padding in front of the equal sign than it would...

i.e. we want it to be

```
$server = 'localhost';    
$port   = 80;
```

But I guess it is not that way.

So my question is what is such option?

[image]

Comment: Update: this issue's status has been changed to RESOLVED FIXED.  This means, assuming that the patch is accepted, that the fix should be integrated into the main branch in a few days (Nov 4, 2011)http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=187734

Comment: Cool! It said will be ready in 7.1 i.e. this December; a bit long though :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** As of **20th of July 2018** this feature is working as expected. Once you save the settings as shown in question, you can use the 'auto format' feature ( <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> ) to align the code based on assignment operator.

---

You are correct in thinking that this option is for aligning multi-line assignments.  However, it appears that this is an [issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=187734) which has not yet been fixed.

I have voted for it and it would be advisable that you do the same.  To vote on an issue, you'll need to register for an account and sign in.  Once signed in, visit the issue and click on the `vote` link which is next to the `priority` section.

Comment: FYI Here's a blog talking about the new feature http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/formatting_group_multiline_alignment_added

Comment: Hi, it's a little later, i agree, but on Netbeans 8.x i cannot get this to work. It's checked in the options, but how to use it then? I select the line block, i click on `Source` - > `format` and nothing happen. Any idea?